# Cannot install Visual Studio 2017 due to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration package install failure

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I cannot install the above mentioned package, which is requied to proceed the Visual Studio install. I checked on Microsoft's forums for solution but no luck. 
I unchecked read-only checkbox in the root of the directory, also manually recreated x64 and x86 folders. The permissions on the users are as they should be also the cleaner app didn't help. I am using the 1809 Windows edition. The current VS version is 15.9.4. 
The log is the following:

```
Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration,version=1.18.21.37008' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1317
Details
MSI: C:\TempTmp\Nova mapa\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration,version=1.18.21.37008\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.msi, Properties: REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 ALLUSERS="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" 
Return code: 1603
Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
Message Id: 1317
Message Details: An error occurred while attempting to create the directory:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
Log
C:\TempTmp\dd_setup_20181215215511_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.log
 Impacted workloads
Game development with Unity     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame,version=15.0.27005.2)
Universal Windows Platform     development     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.9.28307.102)
Visual Studio core editor     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.27205.0)
Impacted components
.NET Native     (Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native,version=15.0.26208.0)
.NET Native and .NET Standard (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard,version=15.8.27906.1)
.NET Portable Library targeting pack     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.6.27309.0)
.NET profiling tools     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.8.27729.1)
ASP.NET and web development     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions,version=15.8.27825.0)
Blend for Visual Studio     (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.6.27406.0)
C# and Visual Basic     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.8.27729.1)
ClickOnce Publishing     (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.8.27825.0)
Data sources and service references     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.6.27406.0)
Developer Analytics tools     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.8.27825.0)
Image and 3D model editors     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics,version=15.6.27406.0)
JavaScript and TypeScript language support     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.9.28125.51)
JavaScript diagnostics     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,version=15.8.27729.1)
NuGet package manager     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,version=15.9.28016.0)
Universal Windows Platform tools     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.9.28119.51)
Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.9.28307.102)
Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.9.28307.102)
Visual Studio core editor     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.8.27729.1)
Visual Studio Tools for Unity     (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity,version=15.7.27617.1)
WebSocket4Net     (Component.WebSocket,version=15.0.26606.0)
```

**Update 1.1.2019** 
I contacted the Microsoft support over chat, but didn't get any further. I was told to try to install an earlier release. I ended up formatting my SSD and installing all the software all over. It luckily succeeded. I am providing a  [vslogs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An_0fA78V4CuleMMgDdEgQCsoEzDWw) overview of the error, before the format.

Comment: Hi, Please check the security of this folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup and make sure the SYSTEM and Administrators have the full control/read/write permission on this folder. Rename this setup folder and check if you have specialized anti-virus, app-blocker, or GPO based permission software installed that maybe be denying access to this location. Temporarily disabling Windows Defender and\or Windows Defender Controlled Folder Access, reboot and run VS installer as administrator to try it again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. I ran the VS installer with Administrator rights, checked the permissions (the SYSTEM and Administrators have full access), and temporarily disabled Windows Defender, but it still didn't help. I tried to install the Community version. I'll try to install the other two versions and see how things gonna work out. edit: Professional version also hangs by this package.

Comment: I even tried to install the earlier version, but still no luck.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply, please try to create a new administrator account or perform a clean boot: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows to have a try. If this issue persists, please follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/05/10/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility/ to collect the installation logs and upload to https://onedrive.live.com/, share the link in here.

Comment: Hi! No problem, I have updated my question with the link.